# set "destroy upgrade" to false on socketio

Tags: node.js

I use code below to run a server side socket

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');
io.set('destroy upgrade',false);

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
  // Send HTML headers and message
  res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
  res.end('<h1>Hello  !</h1>');
});

server.listen(8080);

var socket = io.listen(server);


socket.on('connection', function(client){   

    client.on('message',function(event){ 
        console.log('Received message from client!',event);
    });

    client.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('Server has disconnected');
    });
});
```

but it always reports

```
typeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'
```

if I remove the line

```
    io.set('destroy upgrade',false);
```

it will work, but the line above is necessary for me

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually want to call `set` on the result of `io.listen` (in your case, `socket`), not on `io` itself.  So after the `io.listen` line:

```
socket.set('destroy upgrade', false);
```

Or you can pass arguments to `io.listen` directly:

```
var socket = io.listen(server, { 'destroy upgrade': false });
```